# Realtime volume normalization

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, pulseaudio, alsa

I don't like having to adjust the volume when I'm steaming a movie, but it always seems like the dialogue is too low and the action scenes are too loud. So I'm looking for a solution.

Some background: I'm currently running arch and would like to first develop a solution that will work there. The end goal is to have a solution running on a raspberry pi. I'll split the audio from an HDMI input, run an analogue signal to the pi and send the output to a speaker.

Replacing /etc/asound.conf with the following is the only thing I've been able to find online.

```
pcm.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm "plug:ladcomp_compressor"
    capture.pcm "plug:dsnoop" 
}

pcm.ladcomp_compressor {
    type ladspa
    slave.pcm "ladcomp_limiter";
    path "/usr/lib/ladspa";
    plugins [
    {
        label dysonCompress
        input {
            #peak limit, release time, fast ratio, ratio
            controls [0 1 0.5 0.99]
        }
    }
    ]
}

pcm.ladcomp_limiter {
    type ladspa
    slave.pcm "plug:dmix"
    path "/usr/lib/ladspa";
    plugins [
    {
        label fastLookaheadLimiter
        input {
            #InputGain(Db) -20 -> +20 ; Limit (db) -20 -> 0 ; Release time (s) 0.01 -> 2
            controls [ 20 0 0.8  ]
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

(From a Reddit post https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/of6bh/realtime_volume_normalization/) But I'm not sure it is working. Can someone explain how this config is working or share better ideas.

Comment: What sort of audio input and output it it? Do you have surround sound or just stereo?

Comment: I'm not really sure about input... I guess it would depend on the stream. However it all gets compressed down into two channel. Stereo speakers for the laptop and RCA for the HDMI / pi combo.

Comment: I'm so sick of actors whispering their dialogue with over-loud music/explosions/other noises that I routinely turn on subtitles whenever they're available.   Avoiding hollywood garbage also helps.

Comment: It's just that if you can adjust the centre channel of surround sound, even before mixing it to stereo, that may allow you to adjust the dialogue on its own. How to do that, I don't know, but maybe something to look into.

Comment: Guess: The 5.1 to stereo downmix of your media player doesn't emphasize the center channel enough, so you really want to change the downmix instead of using a compressor for stereo. Also, the sound for some movies is just made this way - action noises are way too loud, no matter what you do.

Comment: Apart from ignoring Hollywood garbage, there is not much more that can be done reliably. If you find a good and inexpensive solution for normalising sound with domestic equipment, you will earn millions selling that for cable/TV companies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the config you have there is really aiming to solve your problem, even though you aren't the only person complaining about the legibility of dialogue.

This config, though, is for averaging out the volume of generally separate sound sources, such as switching between songs, or when louder adverts start. It runs the sound firstly through a [limiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limiter) to keep the volume within set bounds, then a [compressor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression) to average out the sound, leveling off the peaks and raising up other bits.

Whether this is a good idea on audio sources that will already have been mastered to within an inch of their lives is probably not for me to say..

Admittedly this isn't much help for you, but the only suggestions I can think of are:

1. firstly playing around with eq settings in the video player you
   choose, as dialogue is mostly limited to a smallish frequency range. You may be able to find advice somewhere online.
2. If you can access surround sound from a DVD etc. you could adjust the centre front speaker volume, as often this is where the dialogue is mixed to. Then there should be a way to mix down to stereo for audio output.

Unhelpfully, I don't know how to do either of those, but this may give you a few pointers on possible ways of dealing with things.

Comment: I see what you are saying about the script above. Yeah, that's really not what I was looking for. I may try adjusting the compression ratio and see how that works.  The difficulty is that since I'm trying to do this with streaming media I don't have any source files or player settings to adjust.  Is there a way to dynamically adjust the gain?